# acos function error in opencv

Tags: c++, linux, opencv

I am writing a code to extract features and their descriptors from 2 images by using SURF in OPENCV. The descriptors are used to match the features of the two images. To calculate the best matches, I have calculated the dotproduct and find the angle between the two feature descriptor matrices. I am getting an error at acos function. I have added the code and the error below..

Can anyone suggest the error in the program.

```
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
      //-- Step 1: Detect the keypoints using SURF Detector
      int minHessian = 400;

      SurfFeatureDetector detector( minHessian,1,3,false,true );

      std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_1, keypoints_2;

      detector.detect( img_1, keypoints_1 );
      detector.detect( img_2, keypoints_2 );


      // computing descriptors
      SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor(minHessian,1,1,1,0);
      Mat descriptors1, descriptors2;
      extractor.compute(img_1, keypoints_1, descriptors1);
      extractor.compute(img_2, keypoints_2, descriptors2);

      std::cout << descriptors1.rows << std::endl;
      std::cout << descriptors1.cols << std::endl;
      std::cout << descriptors2.rows << std::endl;
      std::cout << descriptors2.cols << std::endl;

      Mat a;
      Mat b(descriptors2.rows,descriptors2.cols, CV_32F);
      a=descriptors1;
      b=descriptors2;

      Mat m;  
      if(((descriptors2.rows)||(descriptors1.rows))==0)
      {
               m.push_back(0);
               return 0;
      }

      Mat des2t;
      std::cout << des2t.rows << std::endl;
      std::cout << des2t.cols << std::endl;


      des2t= b.t();
      std::cout << des2t.rows << std::endl;
      std::cout << des2t.cols << std::endl;

      m= Mat::zeros(descriptors1.rows,1,CV_32F);


      Mat dotprod = a*des2t;
      Mat angle ;

      angle = std::acos(dotprod);

      std::cout << dotprod.rows << std::endl;
      std::cout << dotprod.cols << std::endl;

      return 0;
}
```

ERROR:

```
In function ‘int main(int,    char**)’:
surf.cpp:116:29: error: no matching function for call to ‘acos(cv::Mat&)’     
surf.cpp:116:29: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:55:1: note: double acos(double)
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:55:1: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘cv::Mat’ to ‘double’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/cmath:102:3: note: float std::acos(float)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/cmath:102:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘cv::Mat’ to ‘float’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/cmath:106:3: note: long double std::acos(long double)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/cmath:106:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘cv::Mat’ to ‘long double’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/cmath:112:5: note: template<class _Tp> typename __gnu_cxx::__enable_if<std::__is_integer<_Tp>::__value, double>::__type std::acos(_Tp)
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/surf.dir/surf.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/surf.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Is there any way in which we can limit the number of keypoints to the 100 and are the keypoint ordered according to their strength?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to apply acos to a cv::Mat object instead of a double, this your error.

I've never used SURF in OpenCV so I cannot comment on the validity of the code related to this but you should try and get the first element of the Mat **dotprod** and pass that one to acos.

If **dotprod** is not a 1x1 matrix then probably there are some problems in your code.

To get the element at 0x0 in **dotprod** you can do the following:

```
dotprod.at<double>(0,0);
```

Note that double needs to be replaced with the data type **dotprod** is using to store it's elements, this may be something different from double.

Comment: I cahnged the program as below. But I am getting a segmentation fault. What is the error?                                           for(i=0;i<dotprod.rows;i++)
                                                                        {
                                                                                  for(j=0;j<dotprod.cols;j++)
             {
                                                             angle.at<double>(i,j)=std::acos(dotprod.at<double>(i,j));
             }
   }

Comment: the underlaying data type for your mat is probably not double. Check to see the exact data type and use that as the template param for at. You can see the data type by running dotprod.type() and then check that constant against the OpenCV documentation.

Comment: i got a constant value 5.

Comment: Ok, that's a float, replace double with float: dotprod.at<float>(0,0). You can read some more about OpenCV type enum here http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/intro.html#fixed-pixel-types-limited-use-of-templates

Comment: Yup, you're not initializing the angle matrix. Need to do something like this: Mat angle(dotprod.rows, dotprod.cols, dotprod.type() )

Answer (score 2):

Since `dotprod` is a matrix, there is no overload (visible to the compiler) that generates the arc-cosine of each element of a matrix.  If the matrix is a 1x1 matrix, then you need to pass the element of the matrix to `acos()`: `acos(dotprod[0][0])`, or some similar notation.

Answer (score 2):

std::acos() has below 4 variants:

1. float       acos( float arg );
2. double      acos( double arg );
3. long double acos( long double arg );
4. double      acos( Integral arg )

None of these take cv::Mat as an argument. You need to write your own wrapper which would take  cv::Mat as an argument and convert it into either of these variants.